# Schedule SQL Server query csv file export to remote server

Tags: sql-server, csv, scheduled-tasks

I have a requirement to schedule a query and export the results to a csv file on a remote server.

```
SELECT *
  FROM [Database1].[dbo].[Trans]
    WHERE dat_TransDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
        AND dat_TransDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM [Database2].[dbo].[Trans]
    WHERE dat_TransDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
        AND dat_TransDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

UNION ALL etc...
```

The results of this need to be saved to \\A_Server\Share.
Scheduling the task is fine, just need the export to csv.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to export query results to csv files.

Probably your most robust, giving you the most flexibility, would be to create an `SSIS` job.  However this requires coding perhaps beyond what you're looking for.

You could also look into using `SQLCommand` or `BCP`.  I would suggest creating a view of your data (but you can use dynamic sql).

Just search for the appropriate syntax for each.

Good luck.

Comment: You could use the export data wizard to skip any SSIS design, then save that package to the server, schedule it with SQL Agent. I think it'll work with a query, if not I'm sure it would work with a view.